# Mirror/share Android screen to raspberry Pi b+ Openelec

Tags: kodi, openelec, vnc, android

is it possible at all to mirror an Android device to my OpenElec device? It is an rpi b+. Also, I know that this used to be possible with AirPlay. Can you install a VNC in OpenElec?

Comment: A quick search suggests that there is no VNC client plug in currently available on OpenElec. So it's doubtful. Also for mirroring an android device, you need to run `VNC server` on your device. All the "free" solutions I know for that, need an android device to be rooted. If you manage to compile open source VNC client on your own (again I do not have any prior experience with OpenElec but I assume it is a linux based OS ?), it should be possible. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I do have android VNC running on my android device. And also, just FYI, OpenELEC is actually Kodi, which isn't a full OS.